# Error "Operation could not be Completed" when linked-in app installed on iPhone

Tags: swift, xcode, integration, linkedin-api

I am developing an iOS app and I want user can able to login through linked-in therefore using "LinkedInSwift" SDK. I am able to get access token if app opens in browser but if native linked-in app is installed then it gives me error "Operation could not be completed (lisdkautherror-error-5)".

I did not understand why error is occurring when linked-in native app is already installed on iPhone.

Comment: i hope this one will help you https://www.appcoda.com/linkedin-sign-in/

Comment: thank you for the help . Actually fault was, client haven't added bundle identifier in developer account.